# List Addition Not Returning Correct Result

Tags: python

In Python I wanted to find the minimum of integer in the below list,

```
Listproblem=[1,2,[1,2,3],5,[6,7,8]]
```

I wrote two functions

1. To check and convert  all the elements of above list to individual list
2. To merge all the list from function one to one single 'int' list ,like
   Merged=[1,2,1,2,3,5,6,7,8]

Function 1

```
def as_list(x):
    if type(x) is list:
        return x
    else:
        return [x]
```

Function  2

```
for i in Listproblem:
    merged=[]
    merged=merged+as_list(i)
```

however the output of merged is coming as [6,7,8]

Any issues in the logic?

Comment: `merged=[]` is in the for loop. it should be outside

Comment: `merged=merged+as_list(i)` can be shortened to `merged += as_list(i)`, by the way. And `type(x) is list` should probably be `isinstance(x, list)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that saved , silly mistake  from my side :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You positioned in the wrong position `merged=[]`

Right code is (it finds the minimum as well):

```
Listproblem=[1,2,[1,2,3],5,[6,7,8]]
merged=[]

def as_list(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return x
    else:
        return [x]

for i in Listproblem:
    merged += as_list(i)

print(min(merged))
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the minimum without restructuring:

```
def mini(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return min(mini(y) for y in x)
    else:
        return x
```